# Count is not adding correctly and How do you weigh a result and then score results based on the weight?

Tags: mysql

I figured out the issue I was having moving my multiple row results into one row. I am happy with the result. Now I want to sum up the # of passes and the number of fails from my inspection. The count at the end does not give me the right results. both the PASS and FAIL column shows 56 (the number of items in the list of results. I want the count to show the total # of Passes and the total # of fails. I then want to sum of a score based on the total # of passes. so each pass is worth 1.78571429 - which = 100 (56x1.78571429) can someone help me figure this out?

```
SELECT distinct ae_am_inspection_d.inspection_no
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 01 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Air_Vent
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 02 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Appliance
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 03 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Ashtray
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 04 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Baseboard
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 05 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Button_Panel
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 06 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Ceiling
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 07 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Recycling
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 08 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Trash
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 09 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Compost
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 10 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Countertops
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 11 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Cupboards
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 12 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Curtains
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 13 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Dispenser
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 14 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Display_board
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 15 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Doors
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 16 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Drinking_Fountains
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 17 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Equipment
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 18 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Escalator
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 19 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Exterior
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 20 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as RR_Fixtures
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 21 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as FL_Drains
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 22 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as FL_Carpet
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 23 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as FL_Corners
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 24 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as FL_Edges
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 25 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as FL_hard_surface
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 26 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as FL_vinyl
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 27 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Frame_Door
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 28 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Furniture
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 29 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Glass_exterior
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 30 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Glass_Interior
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 31 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Glass_perimeter
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 32 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Grout
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 33 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Handrail
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 34 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Hanging_Wall
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 35 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Hardware_Door
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 36 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Ledge
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 37 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Lighting
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 38 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Liner_Can
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 39 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Locker
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 40 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Matting
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 41 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Mechanicals
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 42 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Mirrors
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 43 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Partition_
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 44 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Plate_Kick
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 45 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Rack
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 46 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Shelving
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 47 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Showers
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 48 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Sills_Windows
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 49 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Sinks
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 50 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Stairs
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 51 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Switch_Lights
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 52 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Telephone
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 53 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Threshold
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 54 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Wending_machine
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 55 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Wall
    , MAX(CASE WHEN ae_am_inspection_d.line_no = 56 THEN ae_am_inspection_d.result END) as Window_Treatments
    , count(if(ae_am_inspection_d.result in ('pass', 'Not Applicable', Null),1,0)) as Pass
    , count(if(ae_am_inspection_d.result = 'Fail',1,0)) as FAIL
FROM ae_am_inspection_d
Where ae_am_inspection_d.inspection_no = '17545'
GROUP BY ae_am_inspection_d.inspection_no;
```

```
inspection_no   Air_Vent    Appliance   Ashtray Baseboard   Button_Panel    Ceiling Recycling   Trash   Compost Countertops Cupboards   Curtains    Dispenser   Display_board   Doors   Drinking_Fountains  Equipment   Escalator   Exterior    RR_Fixtures FL_Drains   FL_Carpet   FL_Corners  FL_Edges    FL_hard_surface FL_vinyl    Frame_Door  Furniture   Glass_exterior  Glass_Interior  Glass_perimeter Grout   Handrail    Hanging_Wall    Hardware_Door   Ledge   Lighting    Liner_Can   Locker  Matting Mechanicals Mirrors Partition_  Plate_Kick  Rack    Shelving    Showers Sills_Windows   Sinks   Stairs  Switch_Lights   Telephone   Threshold   Wending_machine Wall    Window_Treatments   Pass    FAIL
17545   PASS    PASS    PASS    FAIL    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    FAIL    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS    PASS        PASS    PASS    56  56
```

the Count should be 54(pass) | 2 (Fail). THis is an inspection, so every inspection generates 56 lines in the database with the results. I'm moving them onto one line so I can show all results with a score in a report.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are giving `COUNT` a value of either 1 or 0 and so it will count 1 for each value since they are non-null. You can fix that in a couple of ways; either change the `false` value to `NULL` e.g.

```
, count(if(ae_am_inspection_d.result in ('pass', 'Not Applicable', Null),1,NULL)) as Pass
, count(if(ae_am_inspection_d.result = 'Fail',1,NULL)) as FAIL
```

or change the formula to use `SUM` instead. In that case you can take advantage of the fact that MySQL treats booleans as 1 or 0 in a numeric context and remove the `if`:

```
, SUM(ae_am_inspection_d.result in ('pass', 'Not Applicable', Null)) as Pass
, SUM(ae_am_inspection_d.result = 'Fail') as FAIL
```